# How to mount an SD card reader

Tags: sd-card

I have read through many of the help pages around the SD card mounting issues, etc.

I do not know whether they relate to my situation or not.

What is the first command I should type in the terminal to check if my SD card reader is mounted?

I am working with [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 13.

Answer (score 5):

The command

```
df -h
```

should do the trick. It lets you see all the mounted devices.

Note: You cannot mount the SD card reader by itself. You can only mount the SD card inside the SD card reader.